# Firefox Firebug console history

Tags: firefox, firebug

I can't find history of the console.log() ? is there a way to keep or view previous logged messages, my pages keep reloading and redirecting so the logs are cleared !

Answer (score 9):

In the Firebug console tab, click "Persist" and the logs will persist across page loads.

Comment: okay , but I lose them when I switch tabs , is this the limit ?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that Firebug attaches to the page itself, and so can't persist across the Javascript top-level parent `window` object (and tabs, by extension).

Comment: do you know how to save them to local file ?

Comment: Update: In Firefox, press F12, click the 'Toolbox Options' cog, and under 'Common Preferences' check 'Enable persistent logs'.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the firefox extension, ConsoleExport ,Please refer the link http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/consoleexport/ for more info